# socket.io not sending messages to other members of room

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am making a realtime chat application containing rooms. I am using sockets.io for realtime implementation. I stored realtime users in room but whenever any user is sending a new message the other user's component is not re re-rendering. Socket.io is not working realtime. All users are stored perfectly in a room and disconnecting on refresh but the response of new message is not getting realtime. Maybe I am not using the useEffect correctly also I used useRef for socket as there are many re renders. Please Help thank you

Backend Server:

```
const {addUser, getUser, getRoomUsers, removeUser} = require("./socket/users")

const io = require("socket.io")(4000, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User Connected")

    socket.on("joinRoom", ({user,selectedRoom}) => {
        
        const newUser = addUser(socket.id, user, selectedRoom)
        // console.log(newUser.error)
        if(newUser.error){
            return newUser.error
        }
        socket.join(newUser.room)
        
        io.to(newUser.room).emit("roomData", {
            room: newUser.room,
            users: getRoomUsers(newUser.room),  
        })
    })

    socket.on("newChat", ({chatMessage, selectedRoom}) => {
        const isUser = getUser(socket.id,selectedRoom)
        isUser && console.log(isUser.id, isUser.user.username, isUser.room.roomName)
        isUser && io.to(isUser.room).emit("message", {
            user: isUser.user,
            message: chatMessage
        })
        
        isUser && io.to(isUser.room).emit("roomData", {
            room: isUser.room,
            users: getRoomUsers(isUser.room)
        })
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("user Disconnected")
        removeUser(socket.id)
    })
})
```

Users Array functions:

```
const users = []

const addUser = (id, user, room) => {

    const existingUser = users.find((item) => {
        if(item.id !== id && item.user._id === user._id && item.room._id === room._id){
            return true
        } else{
            return item.id === id && item.user._id === user._id && item.room._id === room._id
        }
    })

    if(existingUser){
        return  {error: "User already present"}
    }

    const newUser = {id, user, room}
    users.push(newUser)
    // console.log(users.map((item) => {
    //     return {id: item.id, user: item.user.username, room: item.room.roomName}
    // }))
    return newUser
}

const getUser = (id, room) => {
    // console.log(id)
    const user = users.find((item) => {
        return item.id === id && item.room._id === room._id
    })
    return user
}

const getRoomUsers = (room) => {
    const roomUsers = users.filter((item) => {
        return item.room._id === room._id
    })
    return roomUsers.map((item) => {
        return item.user
    })
}

const removeUser = (id) => {

    const indexes = []
    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        if(users[i].id === id){
            indexes.push(i)
        }
    }

    for(let i = indexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        users.splice(indexes[i], 1)
    }
}


module.exports = {addUser, getUser, getRoomUsers, removeUser}
```

Frontend:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./home.css"
import logo from "../../images/logo.jpg"
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import ChatBubbleOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChatBubbleOutlineOutlined';
import PersonRemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonRemove';
import PeopleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/People';
import { useSelector , useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import JoinRoom from '../joinRoom/joinRoom';
import CreateRoom from "../createRoom/createRoom"
import axios from 'axios';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { io } from "socket.io-client"

const Home = () => {

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser)
  const joinedRoom = useSelector((state) => state.room.room)
  const [createRoom , setCreateRoom] = useState(false)
  const [joinRoom , setJoinRoom] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [inputs , setInputs] = useState()
  const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState()
  const [nameRoom , setNameRoom ] = useState()
  const [chatMessage , setChatMessage] = useState("")
  const [toggleChatMessage, setToggleChatMessage] = useState(false)
  const [liveMessage, setLiveMessage] = useState()
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([])
  const scroll = useRef()
  const socket = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:4000")
    socket.current.on("connect" , () => {
      console.log(socket.current.id)
    })

    return () => socket.current?.disconnect()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.on("message", ({user, message}) => {
      setLiveMessage(message)
    })

    socket.current.on("roomData", ({room,users}) => {
      setOnlineUsers(users)
    })
    console.log(liveMessage)
    console.log(onlineUsers)

  }, [liveMessage])
 
  const getRooms = async () => {
    try{
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/rooms/get" + user._id)
      // console.log(res.data)
      setInputs(res.data)
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setSelectedRoom(e)
    setNameRoom(e.roomName)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    selectedRoom && socket.current.emit("joinRoom", {user,selectedRoom})
    console.log(selectedRoom)
  }, [selectedRoom])

  const handleChat = (e) => {
    setChatMessage(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if(chatMessage == ""){
      setToggleChatMessage(true)
    } else{
      const time = new Date()
      time.getTime()
      console.log(time)
      const data ={
        room: selectedRoom,
        user: user,
        message: chatMessage,
        time: time
      }
  
      try{
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/rooms/newChat", data)
        setChatMessage("")
        if(res){
          getRooms()
        }
       
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }

      socket.current.emit("newChat", {chatMessage, selectedRoom})
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(inputs){
      if(selectedRoom == null){
        setSelectedRoom(inputs[0])
        setNameRoom(inputs[0].roomName)
      } else{
        inputs.map((input) => {
          if(input.roomName == nameRoom){
            setSelectedRoom(input)
          }
      })
      }
    }
  }, [inputs])

  const handleRemove = async (e) => {

    const data = {
      room: selectedRoom,
      id: e._id
    }
    try{
      const res = await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/rooms/delete' , {data})
      if(res.data.message == "User deleted successfully"){
        toast('User deleted Successfully!', {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: 2000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: false,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          });
          getRooms()
      }
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getRooms() 
  }, [createRoom, joinedRoom])

  useEffect(() => {

    const handleKey = (e) => {
      const element = document.activeElement.id
      console.log(element)
      if(e.key == "Enter"){   
        if(element == ""){
          document.getElementById("h-message").focus()
        } else if(element == "h-message"){
          handleSubmit()
        } 
      }
    }

    scroll.current?.scrollIntoView({behaviour: "smooth"})
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey)

    return () => (
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey)
    )
  }, [handleSubmit])

  return (
    <div className='home'>
        <div className='h-header'>
            <img src={logo} alt='logo' className='h-logo'/>
            <h2 className='h-username'>{user.username}</h2>
        </div>

        <div className='h-bottom'>
            <div className='h-roomsContainer'>
              <div className='h-roomHeadingContainer'>
                <h2>Rooms</h2>
                <ChatBubbleOutlineOutlinedIcon className='h-roomChatIcon'/>
              </div>

                <div className='h-roomsOverflow'>
                  <div className='h-roomsItemContainer'>
                    {inputs && inputs.map((input) => {
                      return(
                        <label className={input.roomName == nameRoom ? 'h-roomsLabel active' : "h-roomsLabel"} key={input._id} onClick={() => handleClick(input)}>{input.roomName}</label> 
                      )
                    })}
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div className='h-buttonsContainer'>
                  <button onClick={() => setJoinRoom(true)}>Join Room</button>
                  <JoinRoom open={joinRoom} onClose={() => setJoinRoom(false)}/>
                  <button onClick={() => setCreateRoom(true)}>Create Room</button>
                  <CreateRoom open={createRoom} onClose={() => setCreateRoom(false)}/>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div className='h-chatContainer'>
              <div className='h-chatMessagesContainer'> 
                  {selectedRoom && selectedRoom.roomChat.map((chat) => {
                    return(
                      <>
                       {chat.user.username == user.username ? 
                          <div ref={scroll} className='h-chatItemContainerOutgoing'>
                            <label className='h-usernameLabel' key={chat._id}>{chat.user.username}</label>
                            <p className='h-messagePara'>{chat.message}</p>
                            <p className='h-timePara'>{chat.time}</p>                   
                          </div> 
                         :
                         <div ref={scroll} className='h-chatItemContainerIncoming'>
                         <label className='h-usernameLabel' key={chat._id}>{chat.user.username}</label>
                         <p className='h-messagePara'>{chat.message}</p>
                         <p className='h-timePara'>{chat.time}</p>
                         </div>
                      }
                      </>              
                    )
                  })}
              </div>
                  
              <div className='h-chatSendContainer'>
                <input id="h-message" placeholder='Write Something' value={chatMessage} onChange={handleChat}/>
                <div className='h-chatIconContainer'  onClick={handleSubmit}>
                 <SendIcon id="h-icon" className='h-chatIcon'/>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div className='h-membersContainer'>
              <div className='h-membersContainerMargin'>
                <div className='h-membersTopContainer'>
                  <div className='h-membersHeading'>
                    <h2>Members</h2>
                    <PeopleIcon className='h-peopleIcon'/>
                  </div>

                  <div className='h-membersAdminContainer'>
                    <h3>Admin:</h3>
                    {selectedRoom &&  <label>{selectedRoom.roomAdmin}</label>}
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div className='membersOverflow'>
                    {selectedRoom && selectedRoom.roomMembers.map((member) => {
                      return(
                        <>
                        <div className='h-membersLabelContainer'>
                          <label className='h-membersLabel' key={member._id}>{member.username}</label>
                          {user.username == selectedRoom.roomAdmin && user.username != member.username ?  <PersonRemoveIcon className='h-personRemoveIcon' onClick={() => handleRemove(member)}/> : null}
                        </div>
                            {/* <ToastContainer /> */}
                        </>
                      
                      )
                    })}
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The problem is in the backend server code where I am joining the room. Instead of socket.join(newUser.room) it should be  socket.join(newUser.room._id). I created the room through id the whole room object is not working.

Updated Code

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User Connected")

    socket.on("joinRoom", ({user,selectedRoom}) => {
        
        const newUser = addUser(socket.id, user, selectedRoom)
        // console.log(newUser.error)
        if(newUser.error){
            return newUser.error
        }
        console.log(newUser.user.username)

        socket.broadcast.to(newUser.room).emit("message", {
            user: newUser.user.username,
            message: "Joined the chat"
        })

        socket.join(newUser.room._id)

        io.to(newUser.room._id).emit("roomData", {
            room: newUser.room,
            users: getRoomUsers(newUser.room),  
        })

        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms) 
    })
```